# Delete Rows From One Sheet If Duplicate Values is Found in Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible for VBA to delete rows if there is a duplicate value in another sheet?

For example: I have Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Sheet 1 is my master data and Sheet 2 contains my new data.

Every time I get new data, I'll paste it into sheet 1 and Sheet 2. I created Conditional Formatting for duplicate values using excel in Sheet 1 and it show if there are duplicate values.

[image]

I wish to delete the second row (the duplicate values; leave the master data alone) in Sheet 1 and delete the same match data row in Sheet 2.

Could someone help me build the code to make it possible? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please share sample data.

Comment: I attached the screenshoot since idk why I cannot add the table. Hope it helps,, thank you

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). 

Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 0):

- User executes the `CopyDataRemoveDup()` to copy data from Sheet2 to Sheet1 without duplicated rows and clean data on Sheet2

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.ClearContents method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearcontents?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144095)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CopyDataRemoveDup()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, dupRng As Range
    Dim arrData, arrRes, iR As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' load data from sheet1
    Set rngData = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    lastRow = UBound(arrData)
    ' load data into Dict
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To lastRow
        sKey = UCase(arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 2))
        objDic(sKey) = i
    Next i
    ' load data from sheet2
    Set rngData = oSht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To UBound(arrData, 2))
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = UCase(arrData(i, 1) & "|" & arrData(i, 2))
        ' skip duplicated rows
        If Not objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
            iR = iR + 1
            arrRes(iR, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
            arrRes(iR, 2) = arrData(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    If iR > 0 Then
        ' clear data on sheet2
        oSht2.UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
        oSht2.Range("A2").Resize(iR, 2).Value = arrRes
        ' copy non-existing rows to sheet1
        oSht1.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Resize(iR, 2).Value = arrRes
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @littleturtle Does the code solve your question? If so, the code could be revised for your next question.